# $out in aggregation MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql-aggregation

Can anyone explain me why in Java when i do an aggregation pipeline with "$out" don't write the result in the new collection when i write only this:

```
     Document match = new Document("$match", new Document("top_speed",new  Document("$gte",350)));
     Document out=new Document("$out", "new_collection");
            coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            match,out
            )
            );
```

When I save the aggregation result and I iterate on it, the new collection is created and the result of the match is inside (Java has an error obviously in this case):

```
    AggregateIterable<Document> resultAgg=
            coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(
            match,out
            )
            );

    for (Document doc : resultAgg){

            System.out.println("The result of aggregation match:-"+    doc.toJson());
    }
```

I can't understand why.

Comment: new Document("$out","new_collection");

Comment: If I understand it well, you question is _"Why do I have to read the aggregation result for the new collection to be created?"_

Comment: No, why mongo don't create a new collection in the first example and in the second yes.

Comment: Equivalent in mongo: db.test.aggregate({$match: {top_speed: {$gte: 350}}},{$out:"new_collection"})

Answer (score 2):

You can call *toCollection()* method instead of iterating.

```
Document match = new Document("$match", new Document("top_speed", new Document("$gte", 350)));
Document out = new Document("$out", "new_collection");
coll.aggregate(Arrays.asList(match, out)).toCollection();
```